# Add Additional Content to Paste

Tags: macos, clipboard, iterm2

(I'm using iTerm2 on MacOS, also have a Debian Linux machine)

Does anyone know of a way to paste content that would include some boilerplate text around whatever the actual contents of clipboard is? Maybe not "paste" directly, but some hotkey that would accomplish the same purpose?

I'm updating some config files, and I have an xml blob that needs the same string inserted in two places...the blob is the same every time, but the values change.

I'd like to put something like this in a key-combination, that would pick up whatever I last copied, so I could copy the necessary value, and then paste this blob:

```
<xml>
<tag>$clipboard</tag>
<tag2>$clipboard</tag>
</xml>
```

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include a possible answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I moved it (and updated it a bit, since I'd found a way to make it work better), thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do accomplish my task somewhat faster, though it's not quite what I was looking for in asking this question:

I use bash to extract the value I need from the file (it's elsewhere in the file), then echo it back onto the end of the file with the additional code. Saves some copy-pasta, though still hacky:

```
for file in filename filename2 fileglob*; do
value=`grep thingIWant $file |cut -d ' ' -f 8`
echo "
<xml>
    <tag>$value</tag>
    <tag2>$value</tag2>
</xml>
" >> $file
done
```

Note that this adds the blob to the end of the file; you might have get creative with cat/sed/awk if you need to insert it somewhere else. In my case sticking it at the end is fine.